# Como enviar una variable por tipo POST en Laravel - Así sea por AJAX, por ahora solo funciona con el Metodo GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

He estado intentando enviar una variable a la misma vista, por ejemplo yo tengo una tabla Tipo producto que esta relacionada con la tabla producto, estoy sacando el id de tipo producto para que me liste con un botón por categorías con una condición (IF) en el blade.php, me esta validando el id dinamicamente atravez de la URL por el metodo GET, por ahora esta funcionando pero cada vez que preciono un boton si me lista los productos pero el problema es que se recarga la pagína y como tengo algunos checkboxes se borran y el boton de active tambien se desaparece.

La idea mía es enviar el id por el metodo POST mediante AJAX por medio de un evento de que cada vez que precione el boton se active esa función y me lo reciba la misma vista para poder colocarlo en la condición (IF)

en la condición IF `$_GET['variable']` tengo esto este es el id que va cambiando cada vez que preciono un boton.

```
 @foreach ($productos as $producto)
            @if ($producto->tipoProducto_id == $_GET['variable'])
                @if ($producto->estado != false)
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="verDetalle({{ $producto->id }})" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#myModal"><img class="card-img-top"
                            src="{{ $producto->imagen }}" alt="Card image cap"
                            height="200rem"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="card-title text">{{ $producto->name }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <td>
                                    <div id="portafolio">
                                        <input class="checkbox" name="checks[]" type="checkbox"
                                            id="{{ $producto->id }}" value="{{ $producto->id }}"
                                            onclick="agregarProducto({{ $productos }})">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                            bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endif
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

este seria el boton donde estoy haciendo la acción que esta por un FOREACH en el Evento onclick mando la variable por parametro que seria el Id que recibe el AJAX

```
                <div class="btnTipoProducto">
                    <a href="seccionProductos?variable={{ $tipoProducto->id }}"
                        onclick="cambiarProductos({{ $tipoProducto->id }})" class="btn btn-primary">Presione esta si
                        desea este item</a>
                </div>
```

Ya este sería el archivo AJAX donde recibe la variable, no manejo casi AJAX, pero este seria el prototipo que tenía que no me funcionó

```
function cambiarProductos(tiposproducto) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: `api/seccionProductos`,
    success: function (response) {
      object = response;

      var id;
      for (const key in object) {
        var condicion = (key !== 'name' && key !== 'descripcion'); 

        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && condicion) {
          const element = object[key];
          console.log(element);
          id = element;
        }
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Error en consulta a: Tipo Productos.show");
    }
  });
}
```

Espero ser muy especifico, espero que esta pregunta pueda ayudar a otros tambien.
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

para envíar parametros debes agregar la propiedad `data`.  para enviar como `json`

```
    function cambiarProductos(idTipoProducto){

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `api/seccionProducto`,
            data:{idTipoProducto}
            success: function (response) {
              object = response;
              console.log(object);
              ajax = objectAjax();
              ajax.open("POST","seccionProducto",true);
              ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                
              }
              
            },
            error: function () {
              alert("Error en consulta a: Aceptar sugerencia");
            }
          });
        }
```

También puedes crear un formulario virtual:

```
function cambiarProductos(idTipoProducto){
           const form=new FormData();
                 form.append("idTipoProducto",idTipoProducto)
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `api/seccionProducto`,
            data:form,
            success: function (response) {
              object = response;
              console.log(object);
              ajax = objectAjax();
              ajax.open("POST","seccionProducto",true);
              ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                
              }
              
            },
            error: function () {
              alert("Error en consulta a: Aceptar sugerencia");
            }
          });
        }
```